# Unicode Values in Registry (Inno Setup 5)

Tags: unicode, registry, inno-setup

I need to be able to store certain Unicode characters in a few of my registry keys, but am unable to find the syntax to do this in an .iss file. I am using the Unicode version of Inno Setup

The Inno Setup site says this about Unicode values:

> you can for example instead use encoded Unicode characters to build Unicode strings (like `S := #$0100 + #$0101 + 'Aa';`), or load the string from a file using `LoadStringsFromFile`, or use a `{cm:...}` constant.

For example one of the one's I want to enter is the degrees Fahrenheit symbol (`℉`) which is `#$2109`.

I can't put `#$2109` directly into the value string because that just prints out that text. 
I tried to create a `#define` constant but it doesn't recognize the `#` and `$` characters.

So I want:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "MyPath"; ValueType string; ValueName: "MyName; \
    ValueData: "Temperature [℉]"
```

but obviously I cannot put it in directly.

How do I get Unicode characters into the registry section, either directly or via some variable/constant, I'm fairly new to Inno Setup.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure your `.iss` file is [UTF-8 encoded with BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8).

Then you can use UTF-8 strings directly in it (with Unicode version of Inno Setup), as the [documentation says](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=unicode):

> Unicode Inno Setup supports UTF-8 encoded .iss files (but not UTF-16).

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "MyPath"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "MyName"; \
    ValueData: "Temperature [℉]"
```

*(note that the entry syntax in your question is wrong, you are missing a colon and a quote)*

[image]

---

An easy way to save the file in UTF-8 with BOM:

- Open the `.iss` file in Inno Setup Compiler GUI.
- Go to *File > Save Encoding* and select *UTF-8*.
- Save the file.

You need to do this **before** inserting your UTF-8 string. Also note that the Inno Setup Compiler editor cannot display the `℉`, but it will still work ok, when compiled.

---

Another way is:

- Open the `.iss` file in Windows Notepad.
- Go to *File > Save As*.
- Select *UTF-8* in *Encoding* drop down box.
- Click *Save*.

Windows Notepad can display the `℉` (with an appropriate font, like the default *Consolas* or *Lucida Console*).

Comment: Your answer ist just a part of mine. You copy the line in the `ValueData: "Temperature [℉]"` ! And I do the same only I got in the .iss a placeholder like `ValueData: "Temperature [=]"` or a ?. After compile and run **In the registry it is the same content written**.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your answer. You say "change encoding in Notepad++" and then *"Next we use a constant and a function"*. It sounded to me like you need to do both. But maybe you actually mean that the second is an alternative solution. But it's not clear imo.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to write what you need into Notepad++
e.g. : Temperature + (ALT+2109) //

[image]

- Set the encode to UTF-8 without BOM
- select the whole line and (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) copy
- paste to the ValueData the copied line **"Temperature [?]"**

---

```
[Registry]
Root: ... ValueType: string; ValueName: "AString"; ValueData: "Temperature [?]"
```

**That's all**

---

---

**Another solution we use a constant and a function :**

```
FHcnst1 =  #$2109#$20#$54#$65#$6D#$70; // ℉ Temp
```

and we add together (**℉ Temperature Const**)

℉ Temp
erature Const

```
... ValueType: string; ValueName: "AConst"; ValueData: "{code:SetTemperature|1}erature Const"
```

**The function "SetTemperature"**

```
[Code]
var
  UserPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;
  UsagePage: TInputOptionWizardPage;
  DataDirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
const
  FHcnst1     = #$2109#$20#$54#$65#$6D#$70; // ℉ Temp
  FHcnst2     = #$2109#$20;
...
function SetTemperature(Param: String): String;
begin 
    if Param = '1' then Result := FHcnst1;
    if Param = '2' then Result := FHcnst2;
end;
```

**The Result :**

[image]

The Hack:
You must write to the registry three bytes.
Only the Unicode **#$2109** will not work.

A good one is #$20 space (because invisible)

```
FHcnst2     = #$2109#$20;
```

Comment: **What is a overkill ?** Copy and paste like you do and compile and run and the ℉ is in the registry . That's all !! I can not see an overkill !!

Comment: As I've explained in my response to your comment to my answer, I may have misunderstood your answer. Its wording was unclear, imo. But it could be just me. I've removed the comment, as you have edited your answer now.

Comment: I edited my answer only with `Another solution` and `That's all`. IMO you are reading it to fast. :) . Your additional information can be described in a comment with one line. `Just make sure your .iss file has UTF-8 BOM.Then you can use UTF-8 strings directly in it (with Unicode version of Inno Setup), as the documentation says:`

Comment: That one line is actually **the key**. Your answer is **actually wrong**, as you helped me to realize with your last comment. The file has to have the BOM, otherwise Inno Setup compiler would interpret the file as ANSI-encoded. Your answer shows that one should select "UTF-8 **ohne** BOM" (UTF-8 **without** BOM). And that's wrong! This is what I get without your solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDaAk.png - I'm aware that you actually do not save the file, but copy its contents to the .iss - but you do not even mention how the .iss should be saved (neither the encoding, let only the BOM).

Comment: For a copy and paste it's better not to have opened a file with the BOM. Accidentally, the three BOM header bytes could also be copied. **It's just safer** ! **In no case is it wrong.**

Comment: 1) The BOM is not a part of the text in the editor, so it cannot be copied to the clipboard. It could happen only if you opened UTF-8 encoded file with BOM as ANSI encoded - But that's not what you do. 2) Once again, your answer does not even mention how the .iss file should be encoded. So it does not actually answer the question. -- That's my last comment. Let the OP decide.

Comment: It is a common practice to improve an answer with a comment in "StackOverflow". I would have taken your comment in my answer. `2) Once again, your answer does not even mention how the .iss file should be encoded.` Should but not must. OP's question is clearly not encoded !! That's a big **thank you** to point that out. But under my answer is enough space to improve it with a comment.

Comment: I tried using a function much like yours, except the constants were just the Unicode characters that I wanted, but I combined them with a string in the registry section. I also did not have the var section, what is that doing and is it necessary to use the function outside the code section? Viele Dank, for your assistance.

Comment: @LaG, My `Var` section is just a leftover from my code. You do not need the `Var` section. In my answer there is the `function SetTemperature` with the command : `...ValueData: "{code:SetTemperature|1}erature Const {code:SetTemperature|2}"`you will get : `℉ Temperature Const ℉` .

Comment: -->and is it necessary to use the function outside the code section?<-- the function `SetTemperature()`  **is in the [code] section !!**